# How to compute $\int \sqrt{x}\sin\sqrt{x} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

How to compute $\int \sqrt{x}\sin \sqrt{x} \, dx$?

I tried let $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $du=\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and apparently it doesn't work. Some better ideas?

Comment: what do you mean with "it doesn't work" ? can you write the steps and what you obtain ?

Answer (score 4):

Once you set $x=u^2$ the integral
$$ \int 2u^2\sin(u)\,du $$
is perfectly manageable through integration by parts, it equals:
$$ C+4u\sin(u)+(4-2u^2)\cos(u).$$

Comment: Dumb question, but shouldn't you just have $u = \sqrt{x}$ or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt{x}) \, dx = \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}\sin(\sqrt{x}) \, dx$$

Now integrating by parts:

$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}\sin(\sqrt{x}) \,dx = \int x \left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x}) \right)' \,dx =  -\frac{x}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x}) - \int (x)' \cos(\sqrt{x})dx = -\frac{x}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x}) - \int \cos(\sqrt{x})dx$

For $\int \cos(\sqrt{x})\,dx$, I recommend noting that $\int \cos(\sqrt{x})\,dx = \int \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\cos(\sqrt{x})\,dx$, and substituting $u = \sqrt{x}$ transforms this to $\int 2 u \cos(u)\, du$. It's pretty easy to integrate it by parts.